# How to align table headers differently than all other table cells?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm using fixed-width columns with my table, and using both `longtable` and `booktabs` packages (as well as `tabularx` because of `\newcolumntype` command).

In my table, I'll have lots of number data in **cells that I want to align to the right**. However, **I still want to keep the headers aligned to the center**, because some heading text will be broken into two (or more) lines.

How can I solve this? Here is a small testcase:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{Table header aligment}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{D}{m{20mm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{20mm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{20mm}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{20mm}}

\begin{longtable}{DLCR}

\toprule
I want this header text centered &
I want this header text centered &
I want this header text centered &
I want this header text centered \\
\midrule

\endhead

Justified alignment &
Left alignment &
Center alignment &
Right alignment \\

% This row is just to show which columns will hyphenate, and which ones won't
Love alignment &
Love alignment &
Love alignment &
Love alignment \\

\midrule

% I wanna keep the numbers of this column aligned to the right, while keeping
% the headers aligned to the center.
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & 123456 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &   1234 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &    456 \\ 

\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX rendering of the above code]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is there a problem with changing the headers of your table to:

```
\toprule
\centering I want this header text centered &
\centering I want this header text centered &
\centering I want this header text centered &
\centering I want this header text centered \tabularnewline
\midrule
```

Comment: It seems to solve the problem! Thanks! (but I'll wait a few days before accepting the answer, just to see other solutions)

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Still, I'm prepared to bet that you won't find anything much better than this!

Comment: This did not work for me, I didn't use any special table package though.

Comment: @MarcelValdezOrozco You'll have to open a new question with more details than that (include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) if you want any help

Comment: @LevBishop The answer from Stefan did work, though. So I didn't need to post another question. :D

Answer (score 46):

I suggest using

```
\multicolumn{1}{C}{I want this header text centered}
```

`\multicolumn` allows changing the formatting of single cells. Here you've already defined the C type, so just use this.
Though using`\centering` directly in cells works, it changes the meaning of `\\`, so you may have to use `\arraybackslash` afterwards or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\`. Your `C` type has it already built in.

Since you use that format several times, perhaps in further tables, you could define a shortcut for it like

```
\newcommand{\centercell}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}
```

To go further to semantic markup, I would define a head cell style and write just

```
\head{This is my column head}
```

in the document body and define in the header my desired formatting document wide, such as

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centercell{\bfseries#1}}
```

This allows easy and consistent changing later. Imagine, you would decide later to omit the centering - instead of searching and removing `\centering` in the document body it's just a small change in the preamble. Here you could quickly switch to bold or medium typeface or perhaps to `\Centering` of [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e). That's no problem, since you separated the formatting from the content.

Comment: Your solution is also very good, and I've upvoted it too. But in the end I had used Lev Bishop solution. Anyway, thank you for your solution!

Comment: Now the only missing macro to make my day would be something like `\headerrow{spec}{content}`, with `spec` being the usual tabular `c|c|lp{2cm}`. This macro would then apply the given specs to the `&` separated `content` via single multicolumns.

Comment: What would make _my_ day would be if the same macro worked for p/m/b columns and l/r/c columns, and if it didn't require duplicating the column widths for the normal cells and the headers.  See [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173194/passing-the-current-column-width-to-a-macro-for-table-headers]

Answer (score 8):

In 2012 (actually from 2011), we have also the option to use the [tabu-package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu). The problem described here, can be solved by the flexible `\rowfont` command. I have also loaded the ragged2e-package, for nicer ragged (right) text.

You do not need to define the centred, justified, left or right aligned column type. They are already defined. But `tabu` indent justified paragraphs, so sometime a `noindent` is necessary.

To avoid bad spacing (even with `booktabs` loaded), the `\tabulinesep=`-command is important.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[newcommand]{ragged2e}

\title{Table header aligment}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=1.2mm % Always use this command to avoid bad spacing
\begin{longtabu} to 90mm {>{\noindent}X[J]X[L]X[C]X[R]}

\toprule\rowfont[c]\bfseries
I want this header text centred &
I want this header text centred &
I want this header text centred &
I want this header text centred \\
\midrule

\endhead

Justified alignment &
Left alignment &
Centre alignment &
Right alignment \\

% This row is just to show which columns will hyphenate, and which ones won't
Love alignment &
Love alignment &
Love alignment &
Love alignment \\

\midrule

% I want to keep the numbers of this column aligned to the right, while keeping
% the headers aligned to the centre.
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & 123456 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &   1234 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &    456 \\ 

\bottomrule

\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: For the record, `tabu` package is unmaintained and won't work, for example, with the latest texlive distributions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a package **[makecell](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/)**, that defines a macro `\thead` for one column table heads. Alignment by **default is centered**, but you can give optional argument (l, c or r) like this:

```
\thead[c]{header text}
```

The font is by default `\footnotesize`. To redefine it do for example:

```
\def\theadfont{\bfseries}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with `S` table format from `siunitx` package. `\multicolumn` works though, see Stefan's answer.

Comment: It works for `S` columns, if you put `\thead{...}` in additional curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table},
  label = {tblr:test},
]{
  colspec = {Q[m,j,20mm]Q[m,l,20mm]Q[m,c,20mm]Q[m,r,20mm]},
  row{1} = {c},
  rowhead = 1,
}
\toprule
I want this header text centered & I want this header text centered & I want this header text centered & I want this header text centered \\
\midrule
Justified alignment & Left alignment & Center alignment & Right alignment \\
Love alignment & Love alignment & Love alignment & Love alignment \\
\midrule
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text & 123456 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &   1234 \\ 
dummy text & dummy text & dummy text &    456 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]