# Overriding default column alignment for headings - can you explain this behaviour?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Thanks to various threads on this site I have almost managed to construct a readable table! In particular I have added `\newcolumntype` to allow me to insert `\newline` into my tables, and I have constructed a table heading format `\head` to allow me to easily use a different format for the heading cells of the table.

I am slightly confused by the behaviour of my `head` format. The headings seem to align as desired only when I use the `\newcolumntype` to define my columns (i.e. `L` or `R` rather than `l` or `r`). Example below.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centering\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand{\COtwo}{CO$_{2}$\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering 
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{ | R{2cm} | r | r | R{2cm} | }
  \hline
  \head{\COtwo} & \head{\COtwo} & \head{Ozone} & \head{Water\newline Vapour} \tabularnewline [0.5ex]
  \hline
  1.2 & 1.55555555 & 2.44444444444444444 & 1.3\\ 
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blah} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Ends up looking like this:

[image: screenshot of my example code]

I can't see why this should be - why can't my `\head` command override the default column alignment when using `r`? It's not such a big deal to use `R` instead of `r`, but I am curious as I am relatively new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a workaround to avoid using `R` when you want to use `r`.

Use

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\head{\COtwo}}
```

in the cell where you want the contents centered.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centering\textbf{#1}}

\newcommand{\COtwo}{CO$_{2}$\xspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{ | R{2cm} | r | R{2cm} | R{2cm} | }
  \hline
  \head{\COtwo} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\head{\COtwo}} & \head{Ozone} & \head{Water\newline Vapour} \tabularnewline
  \hline
  1.2  & 1.55555555  &   2.4   &     1.3\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blah}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you're totally right, I didn't spot the problem in the normal text cells because the text tends to be longer and thus the header defines the column width so they look centred even when not. I had used [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2927/19440) to help me with my headings but removed the `multicolumn` bit because it seemed to end up making my vertical lines bold too and overriding double verticals `||`. I'll have another go, it looks from your answer that perhaps the bold and the \centercell would be better the other way round. Thanks.

Comment: PS: I don't know what the etiquette is: can I edit the original question to remove the math-mode "red-herring"?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the question to remove that. I'll edit my answer accordingly after that.