# Table heading formatting

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have had this problem before (sort of) - it's related to [this question I asked previously.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138962/overriding-default-column-alignment-for-headings-can-you-explain-this-behaviou)

Basically, I am having trouble with my table headings. I want the headings to be bold and centered regardless of the alignment of the text in the columns below. I have defined a new command `head` to do this, which seems to be working fine except for the last column. If I use `head` in place of `\bfseries` in the last column I get an error

```
! Misplaced \noalign. \cmidrule ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ... l.37 \cmidrule
              (r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-...
```

I have read various things about "mislpaced \noalign" complaints coming from things to do with backslashes, but I don't see why that last column should behave any differently from the others.

I have tried to get the text centered by adding a `\centering` instead but the required `\par` messes up the vertical alignment. Anyway, I don't see that I should have to do something different, but I can't see what I've done wrong?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering % automatically center floats
\makeatother


%Table formatting
%------------------------------
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\centering\textbf{#1}}

%Definitions of useful shortcuts (e.g. to add matrix formatting)
%---------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}         

\begin{table}

\footnotesize
%%%\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.6pt}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} L{1.5cm}  C{1.5cm} C{2cm} C{1.5cm} C{2cm} L{4cm} @{}}

\toprule

\head{Head}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things} & \bfseries Stuff Things \\
\head{Head}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things} & {\head{Stuff Things}} \\

\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6} % no "r" here because it's the last   

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries Subheading}\\% \addlinespce

text & text & some much longer text & text &   some much longer text & some even longer even longer even longer text \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{And here's the caption}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

**Update:**

`\listfiles` gives the following:

```
  report.cls    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class<br>
   fleqn.clo    1998/08/17 v1.1c Standard LaTeX option (flush left equations)<br>
  size11.clo    2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option)<br>
   array.sty    2005/08/23 v2.4b Tabular extension package (FMi)<br>
booktabs.sty    2005/03/16 v1.6180 publication quality tables
```

We are well aware that our latex is very very out of date! Something I am trying to get fixed. I can overwrite locally if necessary.

Just to be clear, the compilation problem arises if I replace

```
& \head{Stuff} & \head{Things}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things} & {\bfseries Stuff Things} \\
```

with

```
& \head{Stuff} & \head{Things}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things} & \head{Stuff Things} \\
```

**Update 2**

I've edited my code above to make it more obvious that this problem is only arising the last column (the first column is L aligned too, but the `\head` command is centering my heading).

As per Johannes_B's suggestion, if I add an extra set of braces to the last column

```
& \head{Stuff} & \head{Things}  & \head{Stuff} & \head{Things} & {\head{Stuff Things}} \\
```

the compilation problem goes away but the final column heading remains left aligned:

[image: table]

Using `makecell` and in particular `thead` seems to work fine, but I'd still like to know what's wrong with my code! Can anyone tell me why I am getting this behaviour?

Comment: Why those ``\let\newline\\``? Remove them and it compiles just fine

Comment: @daleif but then how would I insert a line break into a table cell? Perhaps there is some obvious other method that I have yet to come across

Comment: `\arraybackslash` takes care of that.

Comment: @Johannes_B could you expand on that please?

Comment: Just as @daleif said, leave out what he mentioned. You can insert a linebreak using ` \\ ` because you have `\arraybackslash` in your definition.

Comment: @Johannes_B and use `\arraybackslash` to close off a table row?

Comment: Remember `\arraybackslash` is only needed in the very last column (where without it ``\\`` would have the wrong definition)

Comment: @daleif @Johannes_B Thank you for your comments, but I don't really understand what you mean. And removing the `\let\\newline\\`` does not mean I can replace `\bfseries Stuff Things` with `\head{Stuff Things}`, which is the problem I am trying to solve!

Comment: `\bfseries` has nothing to do with this compilation problem. If you have more problems, please update your question

Comment: I just read your question (had no time before) copied and compiled your code. Everything works just fine (still TL13). Can you add a `\listfiles` before the very first line of your document and show us the result?

Comment: @dalief I don't have a compilation problem unless I format the final "Stuff Things" column heading using my `head` command.

Comment: So your question is basically, *How can i center the word **things** within the column?* in the following example: `\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}         
\begin{tabular}{  L{5cm} }
Things \\
 \blindtext \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
`

Comment: There is a group missing, either enclose your definition with an additional `{ }` pair or the entry. All other Columns seem to be centered, because they are `C` anyways.

Comment: @Johannes_B I've edited my question because I can see that my particular choice of dummy text was confusing matters. I've tried the extra braces, it does remove the compilation problem (thanks!) but I still don't have the centre formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `makecell` package: it defines, in particular, a `\thead` and  `\makecell` commands that suppport common formatting *and* linebreaks inside cells. By default, the contents of cells are centred both vertically and horizontally. Also your table goes into the margin as it is. I changed the environment to `tabularx` and made the last column  of `X` type, redefined so as to have cells vertically centred.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, fleqn]{report}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering % automatically center floats
\makeatother

%Table formatting
%------------------------------
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\hfill\textbf{#1}\hfill\mbox{}}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\small}m{#1}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[nomarginpar,  showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\footnotesize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} L{1.5cm}  C{1.5cm} C{2cm} C{1.5cm} C{2cm}X @{}}

\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Something} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Something Else} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Something Else Entirely} &  \\

  & \thead{Stuff} & \thead{Things}  & \thead{Stuff} & \thead{Things} & \head{ Stuff Things} \\

\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6} % no "r" here because it's the last

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries Subheading}\\% \addlinespce

text & text & some much longer text & text &   some much longer text & some even longer even longer even longer text \\

\midrule

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\bfseries Subheading 2}\\% \addlinespce

text & text & some much longer text & text &   some much longer text & some even longer even longer even longer text \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{And here's the caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

** Comment on the O.P.'s code:**

You do not need `\let\newline\\`, nor the pair of braces around the last `\head` . The problem in the last column seems to come from the fact that you change the alignment in a cell of the last column. I see two solutions (workarounds?):

1. In the ‘head’ row, replace `\\` with `\tabularnewline`.
2. Or keep `\\`, but replace the definition of head with this one:

   `\newcommand{\head}[1]{\hfill\textbf{#1}\hfill\mbox{}}`

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion. Using `\thead` does indeed seem to solve all my problems, and is probably the simplest solution generally, so I will almost certainly go with that. Curiously, the table was not overhanging the margins for me! Anyway, it's obviously just a mock-up not the real thing, so I don't really need to use `tabularx`. However, I still want to know why my code is not working, so I will leave this open for a bit to see if someone can explain.

Comment: Right, nobody else seems to have time or inclination to work out what's wrong, and the use of `\thead` solves the problem nicely and neatly, so thank you very much for your answer, which I have now accepted!

Comment: I've added  comments on your code, and two possible workarounds.

Comment: Thanks very much @Bernard, I still don't understand why it should be just the last column though - the first column works fine and is also `L` aligned

Comment: I don't understand very well myself, but it's clearly linked to the end of row (`\\') and the way `\centering`or `\ragged…` work. I obtain a `misplaced \noalign` in the .log. Unfortunately I don't know the internals of these commands.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway! At least I can get my table looking how I want, which is obviously the primary aim -- the secondary aim being to understand how not to make the same mistake again!